# Truncate function for SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, truncate

Does there exist for SQLite something similar as the [TRUNCATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_truncate) function from MySQL?

```
SELECT TRUNCATE(1.999,1); # 1.9
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this numerically by converting to an int and back:

```
select cast((val * 10) as int) / 10.0
```

You can do this using `round()` and subtraction:

```
select round(val - 0.1/2, 1)
```

Or, as another answer suggests, you can convert to a string.

Answer (score 5):

There is no built-in function that would do this directly.
However, you can treat the number as a string, search for the decimal separator, and count characters from that:

```
SELECT substr(1.999, 1, instr(1.999, '.') + 1);
```

(This does not work for integers.)

Answer (score 0):

To work for integers:

```sql
SELECT substr(100 * 1.0, 1, instr(100 * 1.0, '.') + 1);
```